# How to execute a query with distinct keyword in sqlite in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-sql, windows-8

I want to fetch distinct data from my table but  I am not able to use the distinct keyword with the following statement.

```
var query = conn.Table<taxi_fares>()
```

Please guide me about how I could write this query here in C#.

Comment: You can use the Distinct operator on the result of conn.Table<taxi_fares>(), what problem do you have? Probably do you need to make a distinct based only on certain columns of taxi_fares?